# Rounding number within echo $row

Tags: php, html-table, rounding

I have an html table that echoes PHP values from a database table. In this specific area, the values being echoed are numbers but the decimals are out of control. I know how to round the number as just a PHP variable but how can I round these numbers to 3 decimals while echoing the rows like this?

```
<td><?php echo $row['test1CorrectAcc']; ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $row['test2CorrectAcc']; ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $row['test3CorrectAcc']; ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $row['test4CorrectAcc']; ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $row['test5CorrectAcc']; ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $row['test6CorrectAcc']; ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $row['test7CorrectAcc']; ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo $row['test8CorrectAcc']; ?>%</td>
```

UPDATE

SQL statement to get average of values:

```
UPDATE `staging`
SET `testOverallAverage` = (`test1CorrectAcc` + `test2CorrectAcc` +     `test3CorrectAcc` + `test4CorrectAcc` + `test5CorrectAcc` + `test6CorrectAcc` + `test7CorrectAcc` + `test8CorrectAcc`) /
((CASE WHEN `test1CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
(CASE WHEN `test2CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
(CASE WHEN `test3CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
(CASE WHEN `test4CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
(CASE WHEN `test5CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
(CASE WHEN `test6CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
(CASE WHEN `test7CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
(CASE WHEN `test8CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Why not your write code in loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function:

```
<td><?php echo number_format($row['test1CorrectAcc'], 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format($row['test2CorrectAcc'], 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format($row['test3CorrectAcc'], 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format($row['test4CorrectAcc'], 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format($row['test5CorrectAcc'], 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format($row['test6CorrectAcc'], 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format($row['test7CorrectAcc'], 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format($row['test8CorrectAcc'], 3); ?>%</td>
```

Additionally if you can round it by something like half-up rounding, can use [`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function with `number_format`:

```
<td><?php echo number_format(round($row['test1CorrectAcc'], 3), 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format(round($row['test2CorrectAcc'], 3), 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format(round($row['test3CorrectAcc'], 3), 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format(round($row['test4CorrectAcc'], 3), 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format(round($row['test5CorrectAcc'], 3), 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format(round($row['test6CorrectAcc'], 3), 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format(round($row['test7CorrectAcc'], 3), 3); ?>%</td>
<td><?php echo number_format(round($row['test8CorrectAcc'], 3), 3); ?>%</td>
```

You can use loop for echo:

```
<?php
  for($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
    ?>
      <td><?php echo number_format($row['test'.$i.'CorrectAcc'], 3); ?>%</td>
    <?
  }
?>
```

If i understand, you have sql error when all values are zero, so you can use following query that be written like your query format. First check if all values are zero, then `testOverallAverage` is zero, else same with your calculation.

```
UPDATE `staging`
SET `testOverallAverage` = IFNULL(
        (`test1CorrectAcc` + `test2CorrectAcc` +     `test3CorrectAcc` + `test4CorrectAcc` + `test5CorrectAcc` + `test6CorrectAcc` + `test7CorrectAcc` + `test8CorrectAcc`) 
        /
        NULLIF(
            (CASE WHEN `test1CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
            (CASE WHEN `test2CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
            (CASE WHEN `test3CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
            (CASE WHEN `test4CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
            (CASE WHEN `test5CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
            (CASE WHEN `test6CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
            (CASE WHEN `test7CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) +
            (CASE WHEN `test8CorrectAcc`<> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
        , 0)
    , 0);
```

Comment: Write it with a loop will be better.

Comment: I updated my answer, Thanks for your advance @KrisRoofe

Comment: Thanks everyone! Also, are either of you good with SQL? It's not allowing me to post another question yet but I'm trying to save an average of 8 rows but factor in the fact that the fields may have zeroes. I've updated my code with this issue just in case.

Comment: I add sql query to answer, please check it. @TomN.

Comment: I just ran it but it came back with 0 rows affected and my overall average field is 0 in all rows so it looks like it still didn't work for some reason. Just to make sure, I want to save the average of those fields as testOverallAverage, but I want it to adjust if any of those 8 fields are zeroes

Comment: Unfortunately, it still has my overall average as 0. I tried it with sample data in this fiddle and it seems to work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95a1c/1